# Complex Regular Expression about ":"

Tags: regex

```
some_language_built-in_function(String,'^(?:([^,]*)\,?){1}',1)
```

I am new to regular expression. I know this pattern is to extract some specfic context. Can anyone elaborate this?
I have few questions:
1) the first "^"
2) "?"
3) ":"
4) "\" Is this "\" to escape ","? If so, why?
I can't related these with normal regular expression.

Here is the first line of csv file (to be extract).

```
aardsda01,2004,1,SFN,NL,11,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11
```

Comment: [a-zA-Z][\w\d]*(?=,?) should do it if it is the black portion you want to extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `^`: start of line
- `(?:....)`: non-capturing group (as opposed to `(....)`, capturing group)
- `\,`: equivalent to `,` (`\` is indeed unneccesary)

Thus: start of line (`^`), then exactly one (`(?:....){1}`) of: any number of non-commas (`[^,]*`) captured in the first group (`(....)`), and an optional comma (`,?`).